# How to draw a combinatorial graph with different colors of edges?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

[image]

For example, like above. I've read some examples and descriptions in [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GraphPlot.html), but couldn't figured it out.

Comment: Have you tried writing something down ? If so, please, share your code.

Comment: Do you need the `Combinatorica` package? If not, just use `EdgeStyle` :)

Comment: @Novice Looks like a `PetersonGraph`. Where did you get the image from?

Answer (score 6):

I post this for illustrative purposes based on the title of the question (which is somewhat ambiguous). I agree as Szabolcs advice re: looking at documentation, which is good. Here are some motivating examples:

Your example: another way (exploiting Szabolcs observation):

```
cg = CompleteGraph[6];
el = EdgeList[cg]; 
path = EdgeList[CycleGraph[6]];
    Graph[EdgeList@cg, 
    EdgeStyle -> 
    Join[(# -> {Red, Thickness[0.01]} & /@ path), {Blue, 
    Thickness[0.01]}]]
```

[image]

or if you wanted different colors on the hightlighted path:

```
  Graph[EdgeList@cg,EdgeStyle -> 
    Join[MapThread[#1 -> {RGBColor[#2], Thickness[0.01]} &, {path, 
    RandomReal[{0, 1}, {6, 3}]}], {Blue, Thickness[0.01]}]]

![enter image description here][2]
```

A modification of the documentation to illustrate styles for `HighlightGraph`:

```
ged = GraphElementData["GraphHighlightStyle"]
```

=>:

```
{Automatic, "Dashed", "Dotted", "Thick", "VertexConcaveDiamond",
"VertexDiamond", "VertexTriangle", "DehighlightFade", 
"DehighlightGray", "DehighlightHide"}
```

An example (adapted from documentation):

```
Grid[Partition[
  Column /@ 
   Transpose[{Rest@ged, 
     HighlightGraph[
        cg, {1, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 6}, 
        GraphHighlightStyle -> #] & /@ Rest[ged]}], 3], Frame -> All]
```

[image]

Finally, you have a lot of control with wrapper `Style` or using `EdgeStyle` option of built in `Graph function:

Using `Style`

```
Graph[
      MapThread[Style[#1, RGBColor[#2], Thick] &,
      {el,RandomReal[{0, 1}, {Length@el, 3}]}]
       ]
```

[image]

Using `EdgeStyle`:

```
Graph[MapThread[
   Style[#1, RGBColor[#2], Thick] &, {el, 
    RandomReal[{0, 1}, {Length@el, 3}]}]]]
Graph[el, 
 EdgeStyle -> 
  MapThread[#1 -> {RGBColor[#2], Thick} &, {el, 
    RandomReal[{0, 1}, {Length@el, 3}]}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Look up [`HighlightGraph`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HighlightGraph.html).

```
HighlightGraph[
 CompleteGraph[5],
 EdgeList@CycleGraph[5]
]
```

(This solution is based on the accidental fact that CompleteGraph and CycleGraph name and connect the vertices in the same order, i.e. 1--2--3--4--5--1)

Comment: I would have written: "The solution is based on a thorough forensic inquiry on the accidental fact..." :)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to make an edge rendering function:
http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/EdgeRenderingFunction.html